# sums on arithematic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

if 4 terms are in A.P their sum is 20 and the product of the first term and forth term is to the product of second and third term are in the ratio of 2:3 then find the numbers

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
You need to solve the system
$$4a_1+6d=20$$
$$\frac{a_1(a_1+3d)}{(a_1+d)(a_1+2d)}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

As the number of terms is even, it's beneficial to set the terms to be $\displaystyle a\pm d, a\pm3d$

So, we have $\displaystyle a-3d+a-d+a+d+a+3d=20\implies a=5$

Now from the second condition $\displaystyle\frac{(5-3d)(5+3d)}{(5-d)(5+d)}=\frac23$

$\displaystyle\implies 3(25-9d^2)=2(25-d^2)$

Solve for $d$

Had the number of terms been odd, we could take the terms to be $a,a\pm d,a\pm2d,\cdots$